# Too many interfaces and wrappers?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm slowly starting to get the hang of unit-testing and mocking, but it's a slow process. I have tried unit testing this Active Directory code. The question is not strictly relevant to AD.

```
class ActiveDirectoryQueryer {    
   DirectorySearcher mSearcher;

   public ActiveDirectoryQueryer() {
      var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(...);
   }

   public void GetAllMailEntries() {
      MailEntries =
         mSearcher
         .FindAll()
         .Select(result => result.GetDirectoryEntry())
         .Select(BuildNewADUser)
         .ToList();
   }

   static ActiveDirectoryUser BuildNewADUser(DirectoryEntry pDirectoryEntry) {
      return ActiveDirectoryUser.Create(
         pDirectoryEntry.Guid,
         (pDirectoryEntry.Properties["name"].Value ?? "").ToString(),
         (pDirectoryEntry.Properties["mail"].Value ?? "").ToString()
      );
   }
```

So, I would like to unit test the `GetAllMailEntries` method. In order to do this using MOQ I've had to manually generate interfaces and wrappers for various .NET types, and changed many of the above references to interfaces instead (like `IDirectoryEntry`). Each of the `IXxxx` interfaces below has an associated wrapper class `XxxxWrapper`. In total I added at least 12 new source files just for this one test. Here's what I've ended up with for the unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestGetAllMailEntries() {
   var mockSearcher = new Mock<IDirectorySearcher>();
   var mockResultCollection = new Mock<ISearchResultCollection>();
   var mockSearchResult = new Mock<ISearchResult>();
   var mockDirectoryEntry = new Mock<IDirectoryEntry>();
   var mockPropertyCollection = new Mock<IPropertyCollection>();
   var nameMockPropertyValueCollection = new Mock<IPropertyValueCollection>();
   var mailMockPropertyValueCollection = new Mock<IPropertyValueCollection>();

   const string name = "SomeNameValue";
   const string mailAddress = "SomeMailAddress";

   nameMockPropertyValueCollection.SetupGet(pvc => pvc.Value).Returns(name);
   mailMockPropertyValueCollection.SetupGet(pvc => pvc.Value).Returns(mailAddress);
   mockPropertyCollection.SetupGet(pc => pc["name"]).Returns(nameMockPropertyValueCollection.Object);
   mockPropertyCollection.SetupGet(pc => pc["mail"]).Returns(mailMockPropertyValueCollection.Object);
   mockDirectoryEntry.SetupGet(de => de.Properties).Returns(mockPropertyCollection.Object);
   mockSearchResult.Setup(sr => sr.GetDirectoryEntry()).Returns(mockDirectoryEntry.Object);
   mockResultCollection.Setup(results => results.GetEnumerator()).Returns(new List<ISearchResult> { mockSearchResult.Object }.GetEnumerator());
   mockSearcher.Setup(searcher => searcher.FindAll()).Returns(mockResultCollection.Object);

   var queryer = new ActiveDirectoryQueryer(mockSearcher.Object);
   queryer.GetAllMailEntries();
   Assert.AreEqual(1, queryer.MailEntries.Count());
   var entry = queryer.MailEntries.Single();
   Assert.AreEqual(name, entry.Name);
   Assert.AreEqual(mailAddress, entry.EmailAddress);
}
```

Is it normal to have this many interfaces and wrapper classes? (The wrappers are necessary since .NET types cannot otherwise implement my interfaces.)

Comment: I briefly reviewed your setup and the following strikes me very quickly. Instead of the static "BuildNewADUser" function. Put that into a new service (an interface) and give it just what it needs. For example IActiveDirectoryUserFactory.Create(Guid id, string name, string email) returns an ActiveDirectoryUser. Now you can MUCH more easily unit test your initial class by only having to mock one interface and it's one method.

Comment: @Atoms Thanks, I like that idea somewhat, but I'm not seeing how that would let me not mock the `DirectorySearcher`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think my problem is mirroring the .NET structure too closely. I shouldn't wrap each and every .NET type all the way down till I get to just primitives. Rather, I should take the first opportunity to remove all dependencies as soon as I can. In this case it's with the `DirectorySearcher` class, and the `FindAll` method.

`DirectorySearcher.FindAll` returns a `SearchResultCollection`, but rather than thinking of my "wrapper" class as just an adapter to the .NET type, I should make more use of it.

Ignoring the implementation of `IDisposable` and other unnecessary code, my wrapper had looked like this:

```
public interface IDirectorySearcher : IDisposable {
   ISearchResultCollection FindAll();
}

class DirectorySearcherWrapper : IDirectorySearcher {
   DirectorySearcher mDirectorySearcher;

   DirectorySearcherWrapper(DirectorySearcher pDirectorySearcher) {
      mDirectorySearcher = pDirectorySearcher;
   }

   public static IDirectorySearcher Wrap(DirectorySearcher pDirectorySearcher) {
      return new DirectorySearcherWrapper(pDirectorySearcher);
   }

   public ISearchResultCollection FindAll() {
      return SearchResultCollectionWrapper.Wrap(mDirectorySearcher.FindAll());
   }
}
```

Rather, I should take the opportunity to stop all dependencies right here. I don't have to return a .NET type or even just a wrapper to a .NET type, I can now use this interface to return whatever I want. IE: If what I want to get from the `FindAll` method is a bunch of `ActiveDirectoryUser`s, then return just that.

My code then becomes:

```
public interface IDirectorySearcher : IDisposable {
   IEnumerable<ActiveDirectoryUser> FindAll();
}

class DirectorySearcherWrapper : IDirectorySearcher {
   DirectorySearcher mDirectorySearcher;

   DirectorySearcherWrapper(DirectorySearcher pDirectorySearcher) {
      mDirectorySearcher = pDirectorySearcher;
   }

   public static IDirectorySearcher Wrap(DirectorySearcher pDirectorySearcher) {
      return new DirectorySearcherWrapper(pDirectorySearcher);
   }

   public IEnumerable<ActiveDirectoryUser> FindAll() {
      return
         mDirectorySearcher
         .FindAll()
         .Cast<SearchResult>()
         .Select(result => result.GetDirectoryEntry())
         .Select(/*BuildNewADUser*/)
         .ToList();
   }
}
```

And the `GetAllMailEntries` method becomes simply:

```
public void GetAllMailEntries() {
   MailEntries = mSearcher.FindAll();
}
```

And the unit test becomes:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestGetAllMailEntries2() {
   var mockSearcher = new Mock<IDirectorySearcher>();

   mockSearcher
   .Setup(s => s.FindAll())
   .Returns(new[] {
      ActiveDirectoryUser.Create(new Guid(), "Name", "EmailAddress")
   });

   var queryer = new ActiveDirectoryQueryer(mockSearcher.Object);
   queryer.GetAllMailEntries();
   Assert.AreEqual(1, queryer.MailEntries.Count());
   var entry = queryer.MailEntries.Single();
   Assert.AreEqual("Name", entry.Name);
   Assert.AreEqual("EmailAddress", entry.EmailAddress);
}
```

Comment: This looks much better! I think you're figuring things out. My suggestion above, as you've learned on your own, is largely about removing external dependencies (particularly within pesky static methods). Dependencies are fine, but if they are all internal to an implementation, that's often ideal. The moment you expose an external dependency in an interface, it'll require an implementation or a mock, period.

Comment: @Atoms well... thinking about it, what did I really end up doing? I moved the method that I wanted to test to a different class and ended up not actually testing it in the end... I won't be working on this again till Wednesday, but I'm not entirely sure this is better.

Comment: The reason I made the suggestion is that having that many items requiring mocking for one class is a clear sign that the class is doing too much. You're right that eventually, somewhere, you might end up having to work directly with these active directory objects. But if your design is properly broken down, it becomes much easier to create the unit tests. Put another way; classes are easier to test, but you have more classes to test. In my experience this has always been a good thing.